# Intellij: Warning: 'List<String>' may not contain objects of type 'List<String>' (Suspicious collections method calls)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Below is a code snippet where intellij is throwing a `Suspicious collections method calls` warning, but I don't understand why. The only thing I can think of is that maybe intellij thinks one of the lists could be null, but that also throws the same error.

Is this an Intellij bug, or is there really some corner case that I'm not thinking of?

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        List<String> bar = new ArrayList<>(foo);
        bar.remove(foo); // Warning: 'List<String>' may not contain objects of type 'List<String>'
    }
}
```

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        List<String> bar = new ArrayList<>(foo);
        if (foo != null && bar !=null) {
            bar.remove(foo); // Warning: 'List<String>' may not contain objects of type 'List<String>'
        }
    }
}
```

Intellij version 2022.1.4 Ultimate

Comment: note that `new ArrayList<>(foo)` creates a copy of `foo`, not a list with `foo` in it. Such a list would be a `List<List<String>>`, not a `List<String>`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with IntelliJ thinking that something is null.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `bar.remove(foo);`, **exactly what do you expect that to do**? Why? You have one list of strings named `foo`, and one list of strings named `bar`. The `.remove` method is used to remove an element, right? What does an element of a "list of strings" look like? Is it a list of strings? Or is it... a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> bar = new ArrayList<>(foo);

// bar.remove(foo); This is the same thing as:
bar.remove(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")); // still makes no sense.

// What would make sense:
bar.remove("a"); // remove the element "a"
bar.removeAll(foo); // remove all the elements in foo
```

In short, in a `List<String>`, you're usually going to be calling `remove(String)` or `removeAll(Collection<String>)`, not `remove(List<String>)`, which won't really do what you want.

Comment: `remove` vs `removeAll`... d'oh

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> bar = new ArrayList<>(foo);
```

constructs a list containing the elements of foo, not foo itself,